# Mysql Function in Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle11g

I am using AES_ENCRYPT ('text','key') function to insert password in MYSQL. 
I wanted to use same function in ORACLE but it shows Invalid Identifier (AES_ENCRYPT). Please help

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no AES_ENCRYPT in Oracle

Second if you want to encrypt the password in Oracle then you can use the  [DBMS_CRYPTO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm)

> DBMS_CRYPTO provides an interface to encrypt and decrypt stored data,
>   and can be used in conjunction with PL/SQL programs running network
>   communications.

Comment: @RON:- You are welcome. You can refer this doc where you will find examples and explanation of it: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/apdvncrp.htm#CHDBGJFE